# What is the difference between ./ and ../?

Tags: filesystems

when we specify the file path some times we specify like `./filename` and some time `../filename` what is difference between these two?

Answer (score 22):

`../` refers to the parent folder while `./` means the current folder

Comment: they are just a shortcut, so you dont have to write out long directory names.

Answer (score 14):

`.` means 'the current folder'.
`..` means 'the folder containing the current folder'.

Answer (score 8):

just in case you wonder, `./filename` actually means the same thing as `filename` - however, on unix systems, the current path isn't searched for executables (for security reasons), so you have to explicitly say "look in the current directory"

Answer (score 3):

Both are different. `./filename` points to a file in current directory while `../filename` points to a file in parent directory

Answer (score 2):

Both `./` and `../` are the ways to describe a file-path. As all suggested above you can use `./` while your file is in the current folder and `../` while your specified file is in the parent directory. Generally, it is useful while your current folder and parent folder both contains the file with the same name. Then these are very helpful to get the exact file from the folder you have specified.

**Ex.**

- image in current folder: "./profile1.jpg";
- image in parent folder: "../Images/profile1.jpg:"